# Sytem-wide Hotkey Shortcut(Windows/Qt) : Prevent window lock?

Tags: c++, qt, concurrency, hotkeys, stdafx.h

I am trying to figure a way I can use a system wide hot-key in my Qt application.  To check for messages with `GetMessage`  you need a `while()` loop.  This is causing the window to lock up and become disabled, however functions still get processed for each hot-key.

How can I run the while loop concurrently in a way that allows my `ui` to respond?

---

**Example**

```
#define MOD_NOREPEAT    0x4000
#define MOD_ALT         0x0001

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    RegisterHotKey(NULL,1,MOD_ALT | MOD_NOREPEAT,0x42);
    RegisterHotKey(NULL,2,MOD_ALT | MOD_NOREPEAT,0x44);

    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    MSG msg;

    while(GetMessage(&msg,NULL,0,0)){
        if (msg.message == WM_HOTKEY){
            if (msg.wParam == 1) qDebug() << "Hot Key activated : ALT + B";
            if (msg.wParam == 2) qDebug() << "Hot Key activated : ALT + D";
        }
    }
    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved!  Thank you to [terenty](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/27762).

In short I import message into my own thread after allowing the `ui` to complete loading.

```
#define MOD_NOREPEAT    0x4000
#define MOD_ALT         0x0001

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    RegisterHotKey(NULL,1,MOD_ALT | MOD_NOREPEAT,0x42);
    RegisterHotKey(NULL,2,MOD_ALT | MOD_NOREPEAT,0x44);

    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    QApplication::processEvents();

    MSG msg;
    while(GetMessage(&msg,NULL,0,0)){
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
        if (msg.message == WM_HOTKEY){
            if (msg.wParam == 1) qDebug() << "Hot Key activated : ALT + B";
            if (msg.wParam == 2) qDebug() << "Hot Key activated : ALT + D";
        }
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}
```

Comment: sweet, thanks so much for this post. my first time working with qt and windows apps, all this has been a great timesaver.